# Unknown additional space on <div> top

Tags: html, css

I am creating a table madde with several divs, and I am having an extra space between the first row (styled as head) and the rest of them, only the fist two columns (divs). Here you can see very clear:

[image]

There is no style atribute causing this space, at least I am not able to find the reason of it.

I have reproduced it on jsfiddle and you can see that it also sets the extra space: [DEMO](http://www.jsfiddle.net/3mCDz/)

Here I bring HTML & Syle related code:

HTML:

```
<div class="tableWrap">
<div class="tableHeader">
    <div class="contentColumn60">
        <span class="tableHeaderText">Turno</span>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn20">
        <span class="tableHeaderText">Tipo</span>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn10">
        <span class="tableHeaderText">Editar</span>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn10">
        <span class="tableHeaderText">Reactivar</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tableContent">
    <div class="contentColumn60">
        <span class="tableContentText">Mañana(17:00 - 21:00)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn20">
        <span class="tableContentText">Mañanas</span>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn10">
        <a href="#"><div class="editIcon"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn10">
        <a href="#"><div class="discontinueIcon"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="tableContent">
    <div class="contentColumn60">
        <span class="tableContentText">Mañana(17:00 - 21:00)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn20">
        <span class="tableContentText">Mañanas</span>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn10">
        <a href="#"><div class="editIcon"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn10">
        <a href="#"><div class="discontinueIcon"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="tableContent">
    <div class="contentColumn60">
        <span class="tableContentText">Mañana(17:00 - 21:00)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn20">
        <span class="tableContentText">Mañanas</span>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn10">
        <a href="#"><div class="editIcon"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn10">
        <a href="#"><div class="discontinueIcon"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

STYLE:

```
.tableWrap{
    width: 100%;
    height:380px;
    border:#ccc 1px solid;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    margin: 10px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fbfbfb), to(#fafafa));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb,  #fafafa);
    font-size:12px;
    color:#666;}

.tableHeader{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #EDEDED, #EBEBEB) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    border-left: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    border-top: 1px solid #FAFAFA;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.tableHeaderText{
     line-height: 40px;
     padding: 0 10px;
}

.tableContent{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

.tableContentText{
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.contentColumn60{
    height: 40px;
    width: 58%;
    border-top:1px solid #fafafa;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-left:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.contentColumn20{
    height: 40px;
    width: 20%;
    border-top:1px solid #fafafa;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-left:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: inline-block;

}

.contentColumn10{
    height: 40px;
    width: 10%;
    border-top:1px solid #fafafa;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-left:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.discontinueIcon{
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    background-size: 98%;
    background-image: url(images/error.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.editIcon{
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    background-size: 98%;
    background-image: url(images/edit.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the elements are `inline-block`, you could use `vertical-align:top` to align them as desired. It's worth noting that the default property value is `baseline`; this explains why they were behaving as they were. [**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4gv5/)

```
.contentColumn60 {
    height: 40px;
    width: 58%;
    border-top: 1px solid #fafafa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.contentColumn20 {
    height: 40px;
    width: 20%;
    border-top: 1px solid #fafafa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you. I did not know this property. I'll tick your answer in 8 minutes. Do you know why was I having this problem? Theorically there seems to be no reason for this extra space...

Answer (score 2):

use `overflow:hidden;` for content column60,20,10 it works perfect

Comment: I tried this but it just hidded overflown content, that means half of the row. vertical-align:top worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

add a clearfix or use vertical-align:top and overflow:hidden

```
.contentColumn60:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention. As well this as align top works for me.